# No qualifying bean of type org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In `@Configuration` class, `RestTemplate` is defined as below :

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.build();
}

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

In test class, declared with annotations as below `RestOperations` is defined as:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Application.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")

@MockBean
private RestOperations restOperations;
```

It's giving error stating,

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying 
bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations' available: 
expected single matching bean but found 2: restTemplate,createRestTemplate
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your question may be flagged... You need to provide enough code that will help us "decipher" your issue or at least allow us to test run so we can understand it

Comment: Show us your config class, you autowiring the interface with 2 implementations without specifying which implementation to use.

Comment: You have a bean named createRestTemplate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have 2 different beans defined for RestTemplate, one is "restTemplate" and another one is "createRestTemplate". Hence use @Qualifier and provide corresponding bean id. Refer below,

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("{bean_id}")
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```